# Selenium Webdriver Chrome сайт распознает что я зашел через webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, requests, selenium-webdriver, chromedriver

всем привет, нужно зайти на сайт https://roblox.cashstar.com/
вот скриншот капчи, все это происходит при запуске, imgur.com/a/tTDklpe как видно, могуть быть 4 причины: маленькая задержка между запросами; выключенный javascript; в той же сети что и weddriver находится робот
через chrome webdriver, но при входе через chrome все грузит отлично, а если я зайду через webdriver, меня определяют как бота, помогите пожалуйста, не понимаю как это решить

Answer (score 1):

> меня определяют как бота, помогите пожалуйста, не понимаю как это
> решить

Это не простой вопрос. И решать его надо через множество шагов. Количество потраченных усилий зависит от степени защиты обрабатываемого сайта. Самое начало:

1. При отправке GET запроса на сервер *web-driwer* прописывает в заголовок 'user-agent' своё настоящее название. Надо это дело заменить на любой реальный идентификатор любого браузера.
2. Надо отправлять GET запросы не очень часто. Если будет по 10 запросов в секунду, то сайт сразу поймёт, что к нему обращается робот и забанит Вас. Надолго...
3. Очень желательно иметь список прокси и каждый очередной запрос отправлять через другой прокси.

Ну, это - самые азы... На самом деле, всё гораздо сложнее.

Comment: все это я уже сделал, разные user-agentы, большая задержка между запросами и все работает через прокси, но этого похоже не достаточно

Comment: вот скриншот капчи, все это происходит при запуске,
https://imgur.com/a/tTDklpe
как видно, могуть юыть 4 причины: маленькая задержка между запросами; выключенный javascript; в той же сети что и weddriver находится робот